# Python - Ordering a list numerically

Tags: python, list, python-3.x

I have a list of file names in this form:

```
L='csv (2).zip', 'csv (5).zip', 'csv (1).zip', etc...
```

what is the easiest way to order this data numerically?  So that I have:

```
csv (1).zip, csv (2).zip, csv (5).zip, ...
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can get the number within the parentheses, like this `x.index("(") + 1 : x.rindex(")")`. So, we apply that on each and every element and convert that to a number

```
my_list = ['csv (2).zip', 'csv (5).zip', 'csv (1).zip']
print(sorted(my_list, key = lambda x: int(x[x.index("(") + 1 : x.rindex(")")])))
# ['csv (1).zip', 'csv (2).zip', 'csv (5).zip']
```

Comment: Robust and short, if a bit unreadable. Maybe defining the lambda in a separate variable with a descriptive name would help

Comment: He knows I like one liners :)  Thanks very much for the help.

Answer (score 0):

How could you use this to sort an array in python, for example, if I wanted to print the highest and lowest mark from this code.

```
print("Student Grades" ) #Title of the program

studentGrades = [] # Creating an array to hold the grades 

for i in range(6): 
    grade = float(input("Please Enter percentage: ")) 
    studentGrades.append(grade)

    grade = str(grade)
    saveFile = open('studentGrades.txt', 'a')
    saveFile.write(grade)
    saveFile.close()

print(studentGrades)

gradeTotal = 0

for i in range(len(studentGrades)): 
    gradeTotal = gradeTotal + studentGrades[i] 
gradeAverage = gradeTotal/6 

print"Your average grade is", gradeAverage, "%"
```